# The FocusRing is not appearing on control

Tags: internet-explorer-8, focus, radgrid, tabbing

In my application we have a RadGrid on which we can double click and have a row in the editable mode in the table. There are bunch of controls in the row and one of the column has checkbox and other has few links ( tag) when I jump from one control to other by tabbing.. the other controls like text and combo gets the focus... however the check box and links despite havig the focus do not show the Focus Ring around it

This code works perfectly in Chrome where as not in IE8.

Anyone has any suggestions or pointers.

Kind regards,
Prashant

Answer (score 0):

Finally after lots of trial and error I figured out the issue is with the positioning of the control in the telerik grid. When I added the CSS "position : absolute" to control it started to work.